# How can I get the print_leaderboard() function to work properly and print the top 3 people on the leaderboard?

Tags: python, leaderboard

I am having trouble with getting the names and scores I am appending to scoreboard list to show the top 3 when the print_leaderboard() function is called. Any help would be great!

Here is the code I have.

```
class ScoreEntry:
    def __init__(self,name,score):
        self.name = name
        self.score = score

    def get_score(score_entry):
        return score_entry.score

class Scoreboard:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.scoreboard = []

    def add_score(self,name,score):
        new_entry = ([name], [score])
        self.scoreboard.append([new_entry])
        return ([new_entry])
    
    def print_leaderboard():
        scoreboard.sort(reverse=True)
        print(scoreboard[0:2])
        
        #Get list of scores, sort them into numerical order by score, then use print to display top three by slicing in descending order
        

# Write your methods here
scoreboard = Scoreboard ()
scoreboard.add_score('Alice', 7821)
scoreboard.add_score('Bob', 12103)
scoreboard.add_score('Charlie', 8762)
scoreboard.add_score('Denise', 6753)
Scoreboard.print_leaderboard ()
```

That is what I have tried. But I keep getting the error Scoreboard object has no attribute sort
What can I do to make this function work. I assume I will need to change some of the other defined functions too.

Comment: (1) You forgot a `self` so that you access the wrong `scoreboard` variable. (2) `sort` primarily sorts the first item of the tuple (the name). You can simply set the score as first item instead. (3) You use too many brackets `[]`.

Comment: Thank you Michael, some great pick ups there. I have implemented them into but it still is not quite working.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues:

```
def add_score(self,name,score):
    new_entry = ([name], [score])
    self.scoreboard.append([new_entry])
    return ([new_entry])
```

Not sure why you're wrapping all these things in list literals. You're also not using your `ScoreEntry` class for anything currently. Might as well use it? Also, I don't think this method needs to return anything:

```
def add_score(self, name, score):
    new_entry = ScoreEntry(name, score)
    self.scoreboard.append(new_entry)
```

Next:

```
def print_leaderboard():
    scoreboard.sort(reverse=True)
    print(scoreboard[0:2])
```

This is not an instance method. Notice how this function takes no parameters (unlike `add_score` which takes `self` as the first parameter.) This is a static method (for no good reason?)
`scoreboard` within the scope of this function hasn't been defined, so Python will step out of the current scope and look for that variable in the next more-global scope, which in this case is just the global scope. `scoreboard` is defined in the global scope, but it's bound to a `Scoreboard` object, not a list. Lists have a `sort` method, but `Scoreboard` objects do not. I think you just want this to be an instance method:

```
def print_leaderboard(self):
    self.scoreboard.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda entry: entry.get_score())
    print(self.scoreboard[0:2])
```

The `key` keyword parameter is required in this case, because `self.scoreboard` is a list of `ScoreEntry` objects, and you need to define how they can be sorted/compared.

And then in the calling code:
`Scoreboard.print_leaderboard()` -> `scoreboard.print_leaderboard()`

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for all that. I have implemented in the code and it seems to get further but I keep running into this error, AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get_score'

I have updated my code to include:
class Scoreboard:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.scoreboard = []

    def add_score(self,name,score):
        new_entry = (score, name)
        self.scoreboard.append(new_entry)
    
    def print_leaderboard(self):
        self.scoreboard.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda entry: entry.get_score())
        print(self.scoreboard[0:2])

Comment: @NickoToumbas `new_entry` should be a `ScoreEntry` object, not a tuple.